# Using wildcard in notepad++ to replace a very specific range of entries/values

Tags: notepad++, xml, wildcards

Well I'm trying to find out how to use wildcards in order to change a quite specific value, mainly in xml files.

Here is an example of how the file looks:

```
<skill skill_name="alchemy_s18" requiredPointsSpent="12"  maxLevel="3" priority="37" guiPositionID="17" localisationName="skill_name_alchemy_s18"
/>

<skill skill_name="alchemy_s13" requiredPointsSpent="8" maxLevel="5" priority="37" guiPositionID="16" localisationName="skill_name_alchemy_s13"
/>
```

Now I want to change these particular values from:

```
requiredPointsSpent="12"
requiredPointsSpent="8"
To this new value: requiredPointsSpent="0"
```

---

There must be a much simpler way then editing those values by hand, entry by entry.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cygwin and sed. Tick the box for sed as a package to install when installing cygwin and it lists all the packages.

Three files, each contained the word hello, they were created with the echo lines.

Then with one line of sed, I did a search and replace on all files in the directory.

Then I displayed the contents of file 'a' and as you see it says 'book'  so it changed, as did files 'b' and 'c'.

So all you would do is change

```
$ sed -i 's/hello/book/g' *
```

To your search and replace e.g.

```
$ sed -i 's/requiredPointsSpent="12"/requiredPointsSpent="0"/g' *
```

and do

```
$ sed -i 's/requiredPointsSpent="8"/requiredPointsSpent="0"/g' *
```

So you'd want those two sed -i lines.

For a GUI alternative, you could look at powergrep or free alternatives.

These methods also allow for regexes though you aren't really using them for this simple search and replace.

```
$ mkdir asdf1

$ cd asdf1

~/asdf1
$ echo hello>a

~/asdf1
$ echo hello>b

~/asdf1
$ echo hello>c


~/asdf1
$ sed -i 's/hello/book/g' *

~/asdf1
$ ls
a  b  c

~/asdf1
$ cat a
book

~/asdf1
$
```

Comment: Thank you, grabbed dnGREP and after quite some tinkering finding the right combination of expressions to use. It seems to have done the job as I wanted it to. :)

Comment: @Zorkel you can post an answer with screenshots and accept your own answer

Answer (score 1):

edit:
See barlop's answer, which is much better suited for the problem of modifying many files at once. I'm leaving what's below (good for modifying one file at a time) for reference, for now.

---

In Notepad++ you can use Regex portion of the Search/Replace functionality.
In this case I'd use regex like: `(requiredPointsSpent)="(12|8)"` and substitution string like: `$1="0"`.
The important part is that the second group (denoted by `(12|8)`) matches `12` or `8` between `"`. You can use https://regex101.com/ to experiment and have your particular regex explained live, or use http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for a general reference.

[image]

Comment: -1 good regex but you miss the point. He is trying to do this to xml fileS (plural) more than one file

Comment: Ah, well, yes, in that case your answer is much better.

Comment: @barlop Do you think I should scrap that answer entirely?

Comment: I disagree with @barlop: I don't believe the question emphasized making the change to XML files in batch. The question did, however, emphasize using Notepad++. While barlop's answer may be the better one (recommending the right tool for the job), Xupicor's answer is not a bad one.

Comment: @Dane I don't think the question emphasised that it meant files as clearly as it could, though it clearly meant files.  If it was just one file then he could just do search and replace in notepad. I think the answer has some value and is well written, but assuming my interpretation is correct, then the answer just misses the point a bit. But it's still well put and a good regex. So, to the answerer, no I don't think you should scrap it

Comment: And i've removed the -1 since you've now noted the flaw in your edited answer.

Comment: A workaround would be to open all files in Notepad++ and use the "Replace All in All Opened Documents" Find and Replace option.

Comment: @mythofechelon  Interesting idea. This may be relevant to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286433/open-all-files-in-a-folder-using-notepad   "Open all files in a folder using notepad++"

Comment: @mythofechelon that's a good point, but it's still a bit more fiddly. It would work though.